# asp.net search button just refreshing page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to create a search button on my website on my homepage which is an aspx page but when I click search all it does is refresh the page instead of preforming the query, any help would be appreciated 
heres the code for my index.aspx and  the code for my index.aspx.cs page

```
                <asp:TextBox ID="searchtitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="searchitems" runat="server" Text="Search" />
```

```
protected void searchitems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String stext = searchtitle.Text;
    Response.Redirect("search.aspx?searchquery=" + stext);
}
```

Comment: Is your `Response.Redirect` call giving your `stext` a value? And is the redirect working to give you a querystring? e.g. `search.aspx?searchquery=asearchquery`? If so, is the `OnLoad` event of the page handling this `searchquery` variable of the querystring?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean I'm pretty new to c#  and asp but when I press or hover over the button the link doesn't change like it should

Comment: When you hover the button, nothing should be changing in the page. Take off the `runat=server` attribute as it is reloading the page, rather than posting. Provided your button isn't performing a "blank" action, debug your code, and see what happens when you click the button. Stick a breakpoint in at your `String stext = searchtitle.Text` code and see if the `stext` is assigned a value

Comment: Also, I've just revisited your question and didn't notice before; but you need to make sure that `OnClick="search items_Click"` is included in the button code for the event to fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is not working because you didnt call the event on the button

```
<asp:Button ID="searchitems" runat="server" OnClick="searchitems_Click" Text="Search" />
```

add `OnClick` attribute with name of the event you want to call and in the given code the event you want to call is `searchitems_Click`.

Answer (score 0):

definitely when you will click the searchitems page will reload because function for that click is defined on server side.. what you have to do is on the pageload look for the QueryString and get the value of ["searchquery"] then manipulate it as you want..
if you want to not refresh the page use Ajax then...